# How do i compile multiple java files using CMD?

Tags: java, cmd, javac, directory

I am having problems making my classes see each other when i try to compile using command line.

There's about seven java files originally written on NetBeans, all on the same folder.

When i type javac Main.java, it tells me that it cannot find one of the classes in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
javac *.java
```

It might be worth noting that [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) will cause that to expand into (assuming your folder has four java files a, b, c and Main),

```
javac a.java b.java c.java Main.java
```

Answer (score 0):

```
javac *.java
```

or

```
javac file1.java file2.java filewhatever.java
```